# CherryPy: Create Web Service running behind apache2 (mod_wsgi)

Tags: python, apache, rest, cherrypy

I'm new to cherrypy and choose it to create web services for use in other web applications. I want to run it using apache2 and mod_wsgi. I followed the rather [old documentation](http://tools.cherrypy.org/wiki/ModWSGI) and the hello world example worked just fine.

I'm now looking at the turotials and of course the [REST tutorial](http://docs.cherrypy.org/en/latest/tutorials.html#tutorial-7-give-us-a-rest). However I can't get it to run. I get status 500 and an error in the apache log:

```
TypeError: expose_() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
```

To even get that far I adjusted the script from the tutorial similar to the hello world example to work with apache:

```
import sys
sys.stdout = sys.stderr

import random
import string

import cherrypy

cherrypy.config.update({'environment': 'embedded'})

@cherrypy.expose
class StringGeneratorWebService(object):

    @cherrypy.tools.accept(media='text/plain')
    def GET(self):
        return cherrypy.session['mystring']

    def POST(self, length=8):
        some_string = ''.join(random.sample(string.hexdigits, int(length)))
        cherrypy.session['mystring'] = some_string
        return some_string

    def PUT(self, another_string):
        cherrypy.session['mystring'] = another_string

    def DELETE(self):
        cherrypy.session.pop('mystring', None)


conf = {
    '/': {
        'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
        'tools.sessions.on': True,
        'tools.response_headers.on': True,
        'tools.response_headers.headers': [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')],
    }
}
cherrypy.quickstart(StringGeneratorWebService(), '/', conf)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue 1:

```
TypeError: expose_() missing 1 required positional argument: 'func'
```

was caused by the fact that I'm using anaconda python and the version of cherrypy installed with `conda install cherrypy` is outdated (3.8.0). Removing that version and installing newest version with pip solved this.

Issue 2:

Wrong routing.

```
cherrypy.quickstart(StringGeneratorWebService(), '/', conf)
```

should be

```
cherrypy.Application(StringGeneratorWebService(), script_name=None, config=conf)
```

then just entering the path to your script file will work.

Issue 3:

cherrypy sessions are per default in memory and that doesn't play well with mod_wsgi. You need to use file store for session, eg. adjust config:

```
conf = {
'/': {
    'request.dispatch': cherrypy.dispatch.MethodDispatcher(),
    'tools.sessions.on': True,
    'tools.sessions.storage_type': 'file',
    'tools.sessions.storage_path': '/path/to/sessions', # in case of 500 error check privileges of session folder!!!
    'tools.response_headers.on': True,
    'tools.response_headers.headers': [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')]
}
```

}

Comment: It's straight from one of their tutorials. The mistake was `cherrypy.quickstart` vs `cherrypy.Application`. Like this it works and downvote is wrong for anyone having same issues. Note: Personally I needed to get this to work for my pride but I now recommend to choose another framework altogether as documentation is sparse and often outdated.